# How do I update my view when my Model is sorted?

Tags: canjs, canjs-model, canjs-view

I have a CanJS Model.List which I'm rendering using an EJS template like follows:

```
<% this.each(function(item, index) { %>
    <% if(index < 5 ){ %>
        <li <%= (el) -> el.data("item", item) %> >
            <%= todo.attr('name') %>  (<%= todo.attr('distance') %> miles)
        </li>
    <% } %>
<% }) %>
```

In my app where I load the data with `Model.findAll` I iterate all the items and fire off an asynchronous call to update the `distance` property, I have a listener listing for changes to `distance` which then sorts the list based on the distance:

```
$.each(branches, function(i, b) {
    console.log(i, b);
    b.bind('distance', function (x, y, z) {
        console.log("Distance", x, y, z);
        b.save();
        branches.sort();
    });

    // Async call to update distance here...
});
```

The call to `sort()` works, I have various `console.logs()` showing it, but my UI doesn't update.

I'm guessing I need the sort to trigger an event that `this.each(...)` will notice.

How do I get my View to update when the Model.List is re-sorted?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to create a [compute](http://canjs.com/docs/can.compute.html) that returns the sorted list:

```
var sortedBranches = can.compute(function() {
  var sorted = branches.slice(0);

  Array.prototype.sort.call(sorted, function(first, second) {
    return first.attr('distance') - second.attr('distance');
  });

  return sorted;
});
```

This list should automatically update when any of the distance attributes changes.